# tcpdf position footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: php, email, footer, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to add a pdf to an email that is sent out by the system. When the email arrives, the office opens it and prints off the pdf and posts it for customers not setup on the system for email. The problem is that when tcpdf generates the pdf's it is putting the footer directly under the contents of the letter. The problem with this is that the pdf is using the company's letterhead template and puts the header in the correct position, but the footer is supposed to go at the bottom of the page, but it moves according to the position of the content, where as for it to look like the same as their letterhead needs to be at the bottom.

I am currently using the following (I know the POSTS's are insecure, im sorting that one shortly when I go through everything) :

```
    <?php

    $message = $_POST[emailformmessage];
    $cf_id = $_POST[cf_id];
    $leadname = $_POST[leadname];
    $postcode = $_GET[postcode];
    $address = $_GET[address];
    $date = $_GET[date];
    $town = $_GET[town];
    $business = $_POST[businessname];




    $html = "<html>
    <head>
    <style>

    .container {width:680px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:44px;}

    .header {margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; margin-top:15px;}

    .customeraddress {color:#000;margin-left:65px; margin-right:65px; margin-top:25px; text-align:left;}

    .delivered {color:#fff; background:#344EA2; margin-left:80px; margin-top:5px; text-align:center;padding:15px; margin-right:80px;}

    .titles_L {color:#fff; background:#13155C; margin-left:80px; margin-top:5px; text-align:center; padding:5px; width:250px; float:left; font-weight:bold;}

    .titles_R {color:#fff; background:#13155C; margin-top:5px; text-align:center; padding:5px; margin-right:80px; width:250px; float:left; font-weight:bold;}

    .body-text { background:#fff;color:#333; margin-left:65px; margin-top:5px; text-align:left; padding:15px 0px 15px 0px; margin-right:65px; overflow:auto;}

    .terms {color:#fff;margin-left:80px; margin-top:5px; text-align:center;  padding:15px; margin-right:80px;}

    .footer {margin-left:50px; margin-top:5px; text-align:left; font-size:40px; padding:15px; margin-right:50px; color:#000; overflow:auto;}

    .footer a {}

    .footer_left {float:left; width:100px;}

    .footer_right {float:left;}

    .clear {clear:both; float:none;}

    .footerclear {clear:both; float:none; width:100%; padding:8px;}

    .pricerow {}

    .emailpricesgasoil {width:240px; float:left;  padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px; margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;background:#f4f4f4;color:#EE3B33;}

    .emailpricesderv {width:240px; float:left;  padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px; margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;background:#f4f4f4;color:#EE3B33;}

    .emailpriceskero {width:240px; float:left;  padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px; margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;background:#f4f4f4;color:#EE3B33;}

    .emailfueldescgasoil {width:250px; float:left;  padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;background:#f1f1f1;}

    .emailfueldescderv {width:250px; float:left;  padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px; margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;background:#f1f1f1;}

    .emailfueldesckero {width:250px; float:left;  padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;  margin-top:2px; margin:2px 0px 2px 0px; background:#f1f1f1;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class=\"container\">

    <img class=\"header\" src=\"http://key4design.co.uk/chandlers/images/chandlers_header.jpg\" width=\"996\" height=\"326\">

    <div class=\"customeraddress\">
    $leadname<br/>
    $business<br/>
    $address<br/>
    $town<br/>
    $postcode<br/>
    $date<br/>
    </div>
    <div class=\"clear\"></div>

    <div class=\"body-text\">
     $message</div>
    <div class=\"clear\"></div>
    <div class=\"footer\">
    <img class=\"footerimg\" src=\"http://key4design.co.uk/chandlers/images/chandlers_footer.jpg\" width=\"996\" height=\"261\">
    <div class=\"footerclear\"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>";
    $old_limit = ini_set("memory_limit", "16M");
    require_once("./pdf/config/lang/eng.php");
    require_once("./pdf/tcpdf.php");
    $pdf = new TCPDF("portrait", PDF_UNIT, "a3", true, "UTF-8", false);
    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "", 10);
    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, "");
    // reset pointer to the last page
    $pdf->lastPage();
    //Close and output PDF document
    if(!file_exists("./pdf/doc/file.pdf") || is_writable("./pdf/doc/file.pdf"))
    $pdf->Output("./pdf/doc/file.pdf", "F");
    else
    exit("./pdf/doc/file.pdf");
    ?>
```

Comment: i believe TCPDF dont support all css features. Like : `float, padding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you only added an image in the footer, why not just use the [Image Function](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352)

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, "");
$pdf->Image('http://key4design.co.uk/chandlers/images/chandlers_footer.jpg', 100, 350);
// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();
```

You might have to disable the default footer

```
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
```

Comment: If I use image I get : Fatal error: Call to undefined function Image()

Comment: edited. Try $pdf->Image(), also add **x**, **y** coords yourself. a3 portrait size is 297 wide by 420 long so I would guess x=100, y=350 and adjust yourself.

Comment: Thanks, That works now, but it puts the footer on the second page for some reason :-(

Comment: try this `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);`

Comment: Ok, that works now, but is cutting the bottom of the footer off, do I change the coordinates to get it in the right place I presume ?

Comment: yes change the 100, 350 around to position it, if you need to change image width/height can add extra arguments to `$pdf->Image('http://key4design.co.uk/chandlers/images/chandlers_footer.jpg', 100, 350, width, height);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
```

this will prevent tcpdf from auto generating next page and you can adjust your footer on the same page.

Comment: finally, the key to my images being pushed onto new pages!